# How to write in file the output from "tig show commit-1 commit-2 patch"?

Tags: command-line, tig

I'd like to write into a file the output from `tig show commit-97b061ff commit-59466662 patch`

I tried `tig show commit-97b061ff commit-59466662 patch >file.txt`, but the file was empty. I expected that it would contain the patch actual.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'd want to save a patch I'd just do

```
git show $commit > file.diff
```

You can save the current view in tig with `:save-view file.txt` but it's for testing purposes - it adds a lot of additional internal information to diff lines, so if you were to use it you'd have to strip those off.